# Ruby application won't recognize custom exception

Tags: ruby, class, exception, sequel

I have a very basic application here where I am trying to make the errors and exceptions more apparently by declaring a class as that error. The class in question is `InvalidUserId` which replaces `Sequel::DatabaseError`

Within the main application logic, I try to fetch a user from the database by their `id` using `self[:address]`. Because this is a validation method, something the input isn't necessarily an `id`, but an email address, which would cause the model to fail with `Sequel::DatabaseError`.

That's fine and dandy, but my rescue statement does not seem to recognize that `InvalidUserId` points to `Sequel::DatabaseError`, meaning, when that error happens, the code does not step into the `rescue` block. HOWEVER, if I replace `InvalidUserId` in the rescue with `Sequel::DatabaseError`, it does step into the rescue block.

```
module SomeModule

  class InvalidUserId < Sequel::DatabaseError; end
  ..

  def validate
    if this_criteria_is_satisfied?
      begin
        user = App::Model::User.where(id: self[:address]).first
        if user.nil?
          raise InvalidUserId
        end
      rescue InvalidUserId # won't step into this block if I use this class. 
                           # But will step into the rescue block if I 
                           # use Sequel::DatabaseError
        errors.add(:address, "Specified user (#{self[:address]}) is not valid. (code: invalid)")
        return
      end
    end
 end
```

I'm not sure why the application isn't recognizing my custom error even though the error thrown is what I declared it as.

EDIT: It seems this method of making custom exception only allows you to raise, and not catch, is that right?

Comment: Are you sure you're successfully raising? If it's actually raised this code should catch it, though it's worth noting this is really not the way to structure this logic on a local level.

Comment: The `raise` line works just fine. It's the `rescue` portion that doesn't seem to be catching `user = App::Model::User.where(id: self[:address]).first` when it fails with that exception

Comment: I'm asking if that `raise` line actually fires as I have a suspicion that it doesn't. You may be generating another error prior to that which raises an exception and skips over it. Try commenting out your `user =` code plus the `if` and just raise it every time.

Comment: I just commented out the line `user` as well as the the `if` statement, and yes, it raises successfully.

Comment: Where does it get rescued, if anywhere? If you successfully raise it within that block you should be able to successfully catch it.

Comment: The issue is *not* that the rescue fails. The issue is that the line: `App::Model::User.where(id: self[:address])` is what's raising the error, and that error is *not* an instance of `InvalidUserId`. In order to achieve that, the only sensible way would be to *re-raise* an error of the desired class. (Whether or not this is a good idea is another question...)

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, are you suggesting that instead of trying to catch it, I raise that specific error instead?

Answer (score 1):

The database query is what's raising the exception. To get that into your custom class, you need to rescue the normal exception and then raise your custom exception for it to be rescued again. In Ruby this requires another level of nesting (you can't rescue/raise/rescue in one block).

```
begin
  begin
    user = App::Model::User.where(id: self[:address]).first
  rescue Sequel::DatabaseError => exception
    raise InvalidUserId, exception.message
  end
rescue InvalidUserId
  # ...
end
```

Doesn't seem worth it to me unless you actually let the exception go. Immediately rescuing it kinda defeats the point...